# Are the two different categories of angels there to capture the soul in this Hadith?

Tags: hadith-interpretation, death

In the following hadith:

> Abu Sa'id Al-Khudri (May Allah be pleased with him) reported: Prophet
>   of Allah () said: "There was a man from among a nation before you who
>   killed ninety-nine people and then made an inquiry about the most
>   learned person on the earth. He was directed to a monk. He came to him
>   and told him that he had killed ninety-nine people and asked him if
>   there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted. He replied in
>   the negative and the man killed him also completing one hundred. He
>   then asked about the most learned man in the earth. He was directed to
>   a scholar. He told him that he had killed one hundred people and asked
>   him if there was any chance for his repentance to be accepted. He
>   replied in the affirmative and asked, 'Who stands between you and
>   repentance? Go to such and such land; there (you will find) people
>   devoted to prayer and worship of Allah, join them in worship, and do
>   not come back to your land because it is an evil place.' So he went
>   away and hardly had he covered half the distance when death overtook
>   him; and **there was a dispute between the angels of mercy and the
>   angels of torment**. The angels of mercy pleaded, 'This man has come
>   with a repenting heart to Allah,' and the angels of punishment argued,
>   'He never did a virtuous deed in his life.' Then there appeared
>   another angel in the form of a human being and the contending angels
>   agreed to make him arbiter between them. He said, 'Measure the
>   distance between the two lands. He will be considered belonging to the
>   land to which he is nearer.' They measured and found him closer to the
>   land (land of piety) where he intended to go, and so **the angels of
>   mercy collected his soul**".
>
> <sub>[Al-Bukhari and Muslim](https://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/20)</sub>

It mentions two categories angels being sent to the dying person. 
**Are the two categories of angels there to capture the soul instead of Angel of Death?**

Comment: There's no mentioning of two angels (but two categories of angels) nor is the story about capturing a soul after death, but about forgiveness or punishment. And there's no single angel who captures souls as the qur'an shows it is a group.

Comment: @Medi1Saif It seems I copied the wrong version. I updated it with the concerned version.

Comment: [Tafsir](http://quran.ksu.edu.sa/tafseer/qortobi/sura6-aya61.html) of [6:61](https://quran.com/6/61) etc.